# jwplayer seek not working after the jwplayer update (version 7.6)

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, seek, jwplayer7

I am using latest jwplayer version (7.6). After the update `seek` function is not working. This is my code

```
jwplayer('player').setup ({
    'file': video_url,
    'provider': 'video',
    'width': '640',
    'height': '420',
    'image': image_url,
    'autostart': false,
    'primary': 'flash'
}).seek(300);
```

I tried jwplayer `beforePlay()` function instead of seek but it doesn't made any change.

How can I achieve this..?

Comment: have you searched/asked [here](https://support.jwplayer.com/)

Comment: @JaromandaX here it is https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16664511-jwplayer-seek-not-working-after-the-jwplayer-update-version-7-6-

Comment: fair enough - you asked that 5 minutes ago as far as I can tell

Comment: Have you tried assigning instance to variable and only than calling seek? `var player = jwplayer('player'); player.setup(); player.seek()`?

Comment: @Justinas no. Can you go in detail please

Comment: @user2584538 First assign `jwplayer('player')` to some variable and only than call it's functions. I think this was issue with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code example would be trying to have the player seek before its even fully setup and playlist is loaded. The best thing to do would have it seek as soon as the `.on('firstFrame')` event is fired, like this:

```
jwplayer('player').on('firstFrame', function() {
  jwplayer('player').seek(300);
});
```

Comment: Thanks you, you made my day Alex